# Raphael, mouseover and mouseout

Tags: javascript, raphael

The objective of the code below is to show the red rectangle when the mouse is over either the blue OR red rectangles. Note that the red rectangle overlaps the blue.

The problem is that when the mouse is over the red rectangle, it starts flickering and/or it disappears, as you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/8Zy3F/5/)

I even added an alert to the mouseover event of the red rectangle, and it's never triggered. What's wrong with this code?

This is the javascript:

```
    var r1 = null, r2 = null, over_r2 = false;
    var paper = Raphael("canvas", 600, 600); 

    r1 = paper.rect(100,100, 200,200);
    r1.attr({ "fill" : "blue"});

    r1.mouseover(function(e) {  
        if ( r2 == null ) {
            r2 = paper.rect(150,150, 200,200);
            r2.attr({ "fill" : "red"});
        }
    });

    r1.mouseout(function(e) {   
        if (r2 != null  && over_r2 == false) {
            r2.remove();
            r2 = null;
        }
    });

    r2.mouseover(function(e) {  
        over_r2 = true;
        alert("Hello");
    });

    r2.mouseout(function(e) {   
        over_r2 = false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems

- You're trying to register a handler on something that doesn't exist initially, `r2`. Just create it initially and hide it. You should have seen an error on your console that `r2.mouseover` is not a function.
- When you get a mouseover on r2, you first get a mouseout on `r1`. To prevent that from doing anything, you can check the event's `relatedTarget` property

See http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/8Zy3F/6/

```
var r1 = null, r2 = null, over_r2 = false;
var paper = Raphael("canvas", 600, 600);

r1 = paper.rect(100,100, 200,200);
r1.attr({ "fill" : "blue"});
r2 = paper.rect(150,150, 200,200);
r2.attr({ "fill" : "red"});

r2.hide();

r1.mouseover(function(e) {
    r2.show();
});

r1.mouseout(function(e) {
    if (e.relatedTarget != r2[0]) {
        r2.hide();
    }
});


r2.mouseout(function(e) {
    if (e.relatedTarget != r1[0]) {
        r2.hide();
    }
});
```